# cannot access a disposed object while updating the database using EF Core and Azure Functions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-functions, dbcontext, .net-core-2.1

I am trying to get the single row from the database with where the condition using EF Core using the below method,

```
 IncidentRequestDetailsModel dbObject = _context.IncidentRequestDetails.SingleOrDefault(no => no.Ticket_No == requestList[i].Ticket_No);
```

also tried this

```
IncidentRequestDetailsModel dbObject = _context.IncidentRequestDetails.Where(no => no.Ticket_No == requestList[i].Ticket_No).FirstOrDefault();
```

and this

```
IncidentRequestDetailsModel dbObject = await _context.IncidentRequestDetails.FindAsync(requestList[i].Id);
```

It is throwing this error

> if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context
>   in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you
>   should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing
>   context instances. Object name: 'uploadContext'.'

My ultimate goal is to Update the DB using the below overall code,

```
 incidentRequestDetailsModelDB.Status = incidentRequestDetailsModel.Status;
 _context.IncidentRequestDetails.Update(incidentRequestDetailsModelDB);
 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I'm using EF Core with Azure Functions and .Net Core 2.1.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with the syntax of your query. It means some part of your code has called the `Dispose()` method on `_context` before the part of the code where you're trying to query.

You need to track down where you're calling `Dispose()`, or exiting a using statement. And ensure that you're not reusing the same context instance across multiple invocation of your Azure Function.